# Show native phone emojicons in the textview

Tags: android, textview, emoji

I have been using the native emojicon in the `TextView` while entering the text.  But I am getting the issue in which some characters are being shown which are not understandable. May be unicode issue. Please help me how I can show the emojicons in across all the devices. I have already used: `StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava` to convert the String into the emojicons.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I got it. My aim was to save the string from the android app to the server and later fetch the same string from server and display it on the android app.

You have to encode the string first into the UTF-8 using the URLEncode.encode(string, "UTF-8") and save it on server/db.

and later wherever you want to use it, just decode it
UrlDecoder.decode(string, "UTF-8")